# how can i enable proguard in react native

Tags: android, react-native, apk, proguard, shrink

hello i want to shrink my apk file in react native with proguard.
after enabling proguard in my bulid.gradle file :

> def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

i got error after run this code:

```
$gradlew assembleRelease
```

error:

> F:\awesomeproject\android\app\build\intermediates\transform\proguard\release\0.ja: D8: Type 'org.conscrypt.conscrypt' was not found,it is required for default or static interface methods desugaring of 'java.security.provider okhttp3.internal.platform.conscryptplatform.getprovider()'

so what should i do now?

Comment: As mentioned in official documentation depending on libraries you are using you should configure proguard file. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: my app is the same react native hello example. so i didn't use any other native library for configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase
```

to the `proguard-rules.pro` file.

Comment: I did this but still getting the same.

Comment: i did this but not fix yet. my app is the same react native hello example. so i didn't use any other native library for configuration.